# Reusing a bit of code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
<Unique code>

<CodeBlock1>

<UniqueCode>

<CodeBlock1>
```

This is the basic layout of my .cshtml page.

```
This is a c# MVC 4 Razor web project.
```

The above code is in my `_Layout.cshtml` page.

What is a way I can remove both `<CodeBlock1>` from that page and move the code to a single place and still show it in two places in my `_Layout.cshtml` page.

I assume I add a `_Navigation.cshtml` (its nav code that is duplicated)

But how would I then show that code on my `_Layout.cshtml` page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your partial view called `_Navigation.cshtml` and then use `Html.Partial("_Navigation")` to include it in your `_Layout.cshtml` page.

Something like

```
<Unique Code>

@Html.Partial("_Navigation")

<Unique Code>

@Html.Partial("_Navigation")
```